# git status is same for all branches

Tags: git

I cloned a remote repository and created new staging and development branches on the base of origin master. I did some changes on staging branch. When I issue 'git status' command on each branch, git is showing the same status, the same changes for all branches! Shouldn't it show the changes only for staging branch where I actually made changes? I'm using git version of 2.7.4 in case it helps. I'm not a git pro, so please help.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying you made some changes, and then checked-out a different branch before committing?

Comment: Yes, you're right @Oliver. Actually I want to create a new branch, do some changes on this branch only. I do not want this branch or changes on this branch affected other branches. What commands should I use? I haven't been using git for long time, and now cannot remember how I used to manage that :(

Comment: Just add/commit the changes whilst you have the branch checked out.

Comment: If `git status` shows changes, then the changes aren't in any branch; they're in your working copy.

Comment: I think you're right @melpomene, what should I do so that changes were only in one branch, not be in working copy?

Comment: @eldorjon Commit them.

Comment: And changed files are being displayed on any branch whether they're tracked or untracked, added or not added yet

Comment: Many thanks Oliver and melpomene! Committing solved my problem! One more question, I remember earlier versions of git used to warn the user if trying to switch to another branch if they didn't commit changes, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: That warning is only when not committing would cause a loss of data.

Comment: Ok @Dan. Now I get it :) thanks!